# Use heredoc inside $(...) instead of `...`

Tags: bash, shell

Right now I have this:

```
db_conn="mysql -sN -u$db_user -p$db_user_passwd -h$db_host -P$db_port -D$db_name"

query=`$db_conn <<-QRY
    SELECT foo
    FROM bar
    WHERE baz = 1;
QRY`
```

But I hate to use backticks for calling commands. How can I write this using the form `$(...)`?

Comment: What's not working? Just replace backticks with `$(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert newline after heredoc delimiter:

```
query=$($db_conn <<-QRY
    SELECT foo
    FROM bar
    WHERE baz = 1;
QRY
)
```

Comment: Kindoff annoying the last `)` has to be in a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use backslashes:

```
db_conn="mysql -sN -u$db_user -p$db_user_passwd -h$db_host -P$db_port -D$db_name"

query=$($db_conn \
    SELECT foo \
    FROM bar \
    WHERE baz = 1; \
)
```

Of course this means you don't have newlines in the resulting string, unless you add them yourself.